# Displaying next row details from database when next button is pressed

Tags: java, database

I am working in a project known as Employee attendance management system.For this I had created a java form.The form contains employee ID,employee name fields,next button.
   If I press next button the next employee details has to be displayed in the above two fields.In order to do this I had used for loop the problem hear appears is it is displaying last employee details from  the database.
My code is:

```
           int i=1;
           try {
           ResultSet rs;
           Connection con;
           Statement st;

          Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:vasu");
           st = con.createStatement();
           for(i=1;i<=5;++i){
        rs = st.executeQuery("select ID,EName from attendence where ID="+(i));
        while(rs.next()) {
          t1.setText(rs.getString("ID"));
          t2.setText(rs.getString("EName"));
          } 
        }
      }

     catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

Sorry for my poor english.
Could any one please help me..
Well Thanks in advance.

Comment: if this code is the one running upon clicking your next button, this will not work. you are already looping in the result set therefore you'll get the last element always. don't put the `rs.next()` in a loop to get a single row but make sure you keep track of where your "row pointer" is.

Comment: "select" all the employees from the database. Maintain a reference to the ResultSet. One you click next, call rs.next, if it returns true, you have another record, otherwise you've reached the end. Don't use the while (rs.next()) {...} loop, this is running you all the way through the available rows to the last record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem in this loop

```
while(rs.next()) {
          t1.setText(rs.getString("ID"));
          t2.setText(rs.getString("EName"));
          }
```

you need to store the values from database in an array and then iterate over it with your (prev,next) button like

```
i=0;
while(rs.next()) {
          dataset["id"][i]=(rs.getString("ID");
          dataset["EName"][i]=rs.getString("EName");
   i++
          }
```

to display information you can use dataset array like

```
 t1.setText(dataset["id"][i]);
```

I have not checked syntax but the logic is correct.

Comment: Thanks for helping me.I got another solution.I just used these simple three lines code without loop.code is:rs.first(),rs.last(),rs.next().

Answer (score 0):

The values are being overwritten each time in `t1` and `t2` when you call the loop. This is why the last record value is being displayed.

Comment: Please give me any suggestion for this?

Comment: how do u want to display the text fields? do you want to append them one next to the other?

Comment: but there are more than one value being obtained.

Comment: The code got executed.Thanks a lot for trying to help me.I used the simple three lines code with out loops:rs.first(),rs.last(),rs.next().